# How to send data as CSV on Eventhub for Azure Stream Analytics?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I am using Azure stream analytics and my input is Eventhub,EVENT SERIALIZATION FORMAT is CSV and DELIMITER is comma(,).My query is select DeviceId,Temperature from input and my output is sql database.
but when my job is running it gives me error like

> "After deserialization, 0 rows have been found. If this is not
>   expected, possible reasons could be a missing header or malformed CSV
>   input"

and 
second error is

> Could not deserialize the input event as Csv. Some possible reasons:
>
> 1) Malformed events
>
> 2) Input source configured with incorrect serialization format..

and i am sending data on Eventhub like This

```
string messageBody1 = "DeviceID:20," + "Temperature:30";
ClientHelper.SendMessage(messageBody1).Wait();
```

Comment: "Device:20" is more akin to JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current CSV format is wrong because you need to specify column names on the first line and related values in the following lines as :

```
DeviceID,Temperature
20,30
```

Paolo

Comment: Hi Paolo ,i am not understand that how we can send data on event hub in CSV format ,bcoz if i create one string with comma then how can i attach header with that string .like this is my code:-                                                                              string data = "Cleo,Smith";
EventData eventData = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
eventHubClient.Send(eventData); in this code how can i add header of CSV. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, you need to prepend the string with the column names in the following way : string data = "Name;Surname\nCleo;Smith" and then send it. You have to use the carriage return as line separator. You need to add columns name for every record you send. Paolo. Of course it works even if you use complete "\r\n" (carriage return and line feed) as lines separator. You have always to send header with columns name because it's what you do in JSON format : { "Name" : "Cloe", "Surname" : "Smith" } so it's the same for CSV format.

Comment: Is it possible to send multiple lines as values too? e.g.  `string message = "Name;Surname\nCleo;Smith\nJon;Snow\nLeo;Messi\nPepe;Fuentes"`?